# Azure Storage Queue vs Azure Service Bus for poison messages & DLQs

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-storage-queues

What is the difference between Azure Queue Storage and Azure Service with regards to dead letter queues & poison messages?

How do I read the messages from those queues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A poison message is a message that is sent to the queue or topic that the consuming application cannot process correctly.

Once the `DeliveryCount` of these messages reaches the `MaxDeliveryCount` of the queue/topic, they will then be classed as [poison messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#poison-messages).

These messages will be sent to a queue called `<originalqueuename>-poison`.

Both support poison messages but Azure Queue Storage does not support automatic dead-lettering.

This means that while in Azure Service Bus you can set expired messages to be moved into a DLQ for later processing, messages with a TTL value that expire in Azure Storage Queue will be deleted permanently.

Otherwise, handling of messages that will "poison" the system & can never be consumed, is pretty much the same in both offerings.

Both offer a poison queue however only one offers a DLQ.